# “Could Not Access File:” in PHPmail function

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, email-attachments

I am trying to email a file that exists on my server using PHPMailer. When I run this code, I get "Could not access file" and the email sends without the attachment.can anyone guide me how to fix this

```
    $checkyes=$_POST['check'];
    $date = date('Y-m-d');

    $my_path ="/data/data/www/fms/pricelists/$checkyes{$date}.xls";

    include "class.phpmailer.php"; // include the class file name
    $mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
    //$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
    $mail->Host = "mail.authsmtp.com";
    $mail->Port = "25"; // or 587
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Username = "xxxx";
    $mail->Password = "xxxxxxx";
    $mail->SetFrom("xxxxxxxxx");
    $mail->Subject = $sub1;
    $mail->Body = $text_mail;
    $mail->AddAddress("xxx@xxxxxx.com");
    $mail->AddAddress("xxxxxxx@gmail.com");

    $mail->AddAttachment($my_file, $my_path);
     if(!$mail->Send()){
     echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
    else{
     echo "Message has been sent";
    }
```

Comment: Can your server access the file? Control the file permissions.

Comment: yes my server access the file

Comment: So what are the file permissions?

Comment: the permission for this folder "pricelists" is 777

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works:

```
$my_path ="/data/data/www/fms/pricelists/example.xls";

include "class.phpmailer.php"; // include the class file name
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
//$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = "mail.authsmtp.com";
$mail->Port = "25"; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "xxxx";
$mail->Password = "xxxxxxx";
$mail->SetFrom("xxxxxxxxx");
$mail->Subject = $sub1;
$mail->Body = $text_mail;
$mail->AddAddress("xxx@xxxxxx.com");
$mail->AddAddress("xxxxxxx@gmail.com");

$mail->AddAttachment($my_path);
if(!$mail->Send()){
 echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}else{
 echo "Message has been sent";
}
```

Comment: hi i am trying to add the date with the file name but its not adding it showing same error Could not access file: /data/data/www/fms/pricelists/297in2014-01-19.xls,i updated my code can you look

Comment: Where's the variable `$checkyes` ? also, does the file exists ?

Comment: if i do like this  $my_path ="/data/data/www/fms/pricelists/$checkyes.xls"; its working fine the issue when i am try to do like this   $my_path ="/data/data/www/fms/pricelists/$checkyes{$date}.xls";

Comment: Does this file exists? `/data/data/www/fms/pricelists/297in01-01-2001.xls`, the date is just an example.

Comment: what's the output of `var_dump($my_path);`

Answer (score 3):

You added your parameters the wrong way:

```
public function addAttachment($path, $name = '', $encoding = 'base64', $type = '', $disposition = 'attachment')
```

So this would be the way to go:

```
$mail->AddAttachment($my_path . $my_file);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply i tried its showing again like this :Could not access file: /data/data/www/fms/pricelists/

Comment: I've edited my answer. So the second parameter is something like an alias you could specify.