# could not access file error while sending mail with phpmailer?

Tags: php, phpmailer

My email is send with attachments but I get error/message could not access file.
here is my code

```
if (isset($_FILES['file1'])) {

    foreach ($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name)
    {
        $att_key   = $_FILES['file1']['name'][$key];
        $file_name = $key . $_FILES['file1']['name'][$key];
        $file_size = $_FILES['file1']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp  = $_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type = $_FILES['file1']['type'][$key];  

        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "upload/" . time() . $file_name);
        $attchments[$att_key] = "upload/" . time() . $file_name;
    }
}
else{
}

foreach ($attchments as $key => $value) {
    $mail->addAttachment($value, $key); 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [“Could Not Access File:” in PHPmail function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21216883/could-not-access-file-in-phpmail-function)

Comment: my code is working my email is sent with attachments but i get could not acees file error and my email is send successfully. I want remove this warning/message

Comment: Where did you get this error?

Comment: You are using `time()` in moving file and afterwards creating index in attachment array, and it may be possible that value of `time()` gets changed in execution of both code line. Wouldn't it be better to use variable for file name.

Comment: Just set $mail->SMTPDebug = 0; in PHP mailer configuration.

Comment: @SaurabhGaikwad Please try by changing this code. Like,

`$file_upload_name = time().$file_name;
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"upload/".$file_upload_name);
$attchments[$att_key] = "upload/".$file_upload_name;`

Comment: it is already set to zero. can you suggest better code.I am also attach multiple attachments

Comment: it didn't work @umair Khan

Comment: Take a look at [the send multiple file uploads example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_multiple_file_upload.phps) provided with PHPMailer.